# Is there a term for the moment when a lot of users visit/log onto your website at the same time?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for the moment when a lot of users visit/log onto your website at the same time?

Comment: In which context are you referring, from server perspective or a marketing /aesthetic perspective. Just to understand the context of why you're asking.

Comment: This question itself appears to have experienced __________ (insert term here).

Answer (score 47):

In my experience we've generally refer to a **spike** in traffic to differentiate an unexpected or irregular increase from regular/daily **peak** periods. For example, a website may have peak periods around opening and closing time, but a spike might result from an advertising campaign or news article.

[image: traffic spike]

In this example, the "spike" is pretty distinctive compared to the rest of the day and remains unexplained.

Comment: Spike is right but slashdotted is more emotionally laden.

Answer (score 38):

If it is caused by users all visiting from a news site, it is called the [**Slashdot effect**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect) or **Slashdotting**.

[Slashdot](https://slashdot.org/) is one of the first internet news aggregators.   When they posted a news article, it often crashed the sites they linked to because so many Slashdot users would visit simultaneously.

Today the term "slashdotting" can be applied when any site suddenly sends many visitors to another site simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think this is a universal and common term. People who don't use Slashdot probably don't know or use it and many similar terms exist for other big international (like Reddit) and national (like heise.de) websites.

Comment: It would be interesting to list the terms used by users of those other websites.  "slashdotted" is certainly used in cases where Slashdot wasn't actually involved.

Comment: @florianh I disagree. I do not use Slashdot and I know the term. It is the most commonly used term because it was the first (*commonly known, large scale*) place where this happened. I'd say it's a somewhat common term when it comes to website management.

Comment: Slashdotting is only one possible scenario why you might have a peak in users. A lot of website might have "natural" peaks, during for example lunchtime. I do not believe this does answer the actual question, but simply a mention of something that can cause whatever the word the question is looking for.

Comment: I believe reddit calls it "the hug of death".

Comment: If the link is from fark.com then the site is said to be farked.... I think there was a fourth one two (aside from reddit and slashdot)

Comment: @florianh: also, big sites might not recognise the effect of Slashdot as being "a lot of users" and so the terminology might not stick for them. I remember an incident some years ago when someone on Slashdot was worried about slashdotting the BBC website, and somebody else posted a link to their bandwidth chart, where the instant of the slashdotting showed up as a tiny uptick.

Comment: @aslum Digg is probably the one you are missing

Comment: I think the Slashdot Effect is a bit of an outdated term.  Slashdot used to be more significant 10 years ago when the internet was more frail and their website was considered new and innovative (more active users + linking to weaker web servers = slashdotted). I can't imagine their active user-base is nearly what it used to be. That's a term I used many years ago but haven't heard in quite a while. Most younger folks would look at you confused if you mentioned slashdot.  If it was ever mentioned in a tech book, I would guess that tech book is at least 10+ years old.

Comment: In response to the number of people complaining about "slashdotted" being out of date, it's worth noting that a great many things in our language are similarly disconnected from the original context.  Filibuster is from an old Dutch word for pirates, Gerrymander derives from an event in 1812, any case of genericising a trademark also qualifies (eg, Kleenex for any tissue).  Heck, I'm typing this on a computer (the name comes from "person who performs calculations") using a keyboard (originally specific to musical instruments, as in musical key).  Age matters not, only understanding does.

Comment: I used to frequent slashdot, and didn't the term slashdotted only refer to when a site slowed down or stopped working?  Not every site linked on slashdot was "slashdotted," only the ones that stopped working (or became crippled.)

Comment: @aslum `goonrushed` was a term used when the traffic was from members of the Something Awful forums (whose members are called goons).

Answer (score 13):

I would call it a ***Peak*** in visitors. This indicates that we're not having a usual amount of visitors, but more. The peak could be a small peak, or a large peak (a ***spike*** of visitors).

As a unit of time, you could go for *Peak Hour/day/period*.

> **[peaked, peak·ing, peaks](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peak)**
>   1. Nautical To raise (a gaff) above the horizontal.
>   **2. To bring to a maximum of development, value, or intensity.**

Comment: *peak* might not be unusual, e.g. a website has periodic daily peaks. What about a *surge* ?

Comment: As non-native english person, my first association is to *power surge*, electrical. But others might disagree

Answer (score 6):

If you have a sudden **influx** of users that happens to result in your site being taken down, your site has been given what a Redditor would call a **hug of death**.

Answer (score 6):

**ADDOS: Accidental Distributed Denial of Service**

You wanted all those folks to visit, just... not at the same time.

Comment: Although I think the "A" in ADDOS would more commonly refer to "Amplified".

Comment: How about UDDos -- unintended. I am all for creating a new acronym :-)

Comment: I think unintended is better actually!

Answer (score 3):

It could be referred to as a [flash crowd](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_crowd) (from the novel [Flash Crowd](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Crowd)), especially if it was triggered from a post or article elsewhere linking to your site.

Answer (score 1):

I've known this as a "spike in traffic". I find such spikes are more caused by robots that try to hack into the server by trying to request specific URLs in a super short time frame (I say about 20 to 25 requests per second). I find when users visit my site, I see no huge spikes at all since most requests total no more than 50 KB to 500 KB each depending on photo size and when google crawls my site like crazy, I still don't get spikes. It only happens when bots try to hack my server.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper term is Digital Bulge.

Comment: https://secure.static.tumblr.com/144dd939b4712e2900da02c171b59812/hyxow7c/qZtnoq6pa/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_7bjbz178y7sw0g4kcogkk48wg_640.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's **bottleneck** or **rush hour** or even **road rage**. You can call any from the above or even a custom word based on what amount your website/app gets hit by.

Comment: I would not use the phrase "bottleneck" unless it causes a problem - in other words, if twice as many users hit the site as usual but the site continues to operate as normal, I would not consider that a bottleneck. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck

Comment: "Road rage" relates to website hits how?!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I could think about:

**Rush Hour**

like in traffic

Answer (score 0):

If it happens once in a while, I'd add the word **oscillation** with peak and/or spike.

Also, if it happens periodically, I'd add the word **redundancy**.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is called DDOS attack.

Comment: A DDoS attack is not a spike in users. A DDoS attack follows patterns that are clear and is continuous.